# Cohomology of $BE_8$ and $BSU(2)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, classifying-spaces

What are the cohomology of the classifying space of $E_8$ group and $SU(2)$ group, $H^*(BE_8;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(BSU(2);\mathbb{Z})$?

In the paper 
http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/ConMcohomology1.pdf ,
it was given that $H^∗[BSU(2); \mathbb{Z}_2] = \mathbb{Z}_2[u_4]$.
But I like to know the result for integer coefficient.

== added ==

Mike Miller answered the $BSU(2)$ part of the question. There is no torsion 
in $H^*(BSU(2);\mathbb{Z})$. A motivation for me to ask the above question is to find simple *compact* and *simply connected* Lie groups $G$, such that
$H^*(BG;\mathbb{Z})$ has torsions at certain dimensions. So $SU(2)$ is out.

Comment: $BSU(2) = \Bbb{HP}^\infty$. You get the result $\Bbb Z[u_4]$ the same way you get the corresponding result for $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$ - a nice cell decomposition, say.

Comment: You'll find some (incomplete) information on the cohomology of $BE_8$ in the final chapter of Mimura and Toda's book "Topology of Lie Groups I, II"

Comment: $BE_8$ looks like $K(\mathbb Z,4)$ up to all the dimensions that you probably care about: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52286/how-are-the-classifying-space-of-e-8-and-k-mathbbz-4-related/52321#52321 The cohomology of $K(\mathbb Z,4)$ is messy, but you'll find some information here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237469/table-of-integral-cohomology-groups-of-kz-n

Answer (score 8):

I believe Appendix 1. in ``Finite H-spaces and Lie Groups" by Frank Adams
shows that BE8 has 2,3 and 5-torsion. The letter from E8 at the end of this paper is also quite amusing:

....Be it therefore known and proclaimed among you, that my K-theory K(E8) and that of my classifying space K(BE8) cannot be criticised in this respect, at least at the prime 5. Their conduct is such as would be blameless and above reproach in the K-theory of a space without 5-torsion in its ordinary cohomology.

Given at our palace, etc, etc, 
                                        and signed
                                              E8

Comment: Thanks Jeff. But at which dimensions $k$, $H^k(BE_8;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_3$, or $\mathbb{Z}_5$? (I cannot find the paper.)

Comment: I sent you a pdf of the Adams paper by email.